# BitmapImage Image Size Limit

Tags: c#, wpf

When I Use BitmapImage to load image file, a OverflowException was happened (Image Size = 4.83GB).
But I get the BitmapSouce information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), The maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels at 32 bits per channel * 4 channels. The maximum size of a BitmapSource is 2^32 bytes (64 gigabytes) and the maximum image size is four gigapixels. The minimum image size is 1x1. 
Anyone know why ?
How to use BitmapSource to load the image the size is large than 4 or 5 gb ?

Comment: You might be hitting some additional limit, e.g. [ID2D1RenderTarget::GetMaximumBitmapSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: 4.83 GB seems to be the size of the encoded image buffer (e.g. PNG or JPEG). But what is the size of the decoded bitmap?